# Objective-c random point which lies in given cgrect

Tags: objective-c, random, cgrect

my requirement is generating a random point in a given area, i.e i have an CGRect of some space and i need to generate  a rendom point in this rect ..

how can i proceed in this scenario ??

Comment: Are you folks using your close votes, or are you just flagging?

Comment: @Robert Harvey u need 3k rep to cast a close vote :(

Comment: This question can be perfectly answered (create random point within the bounds of a rect).

Answer (score 7):

You should generate 2 random values that lie in range of your rect.

Eg. a rect like this (100,50,300,200) will require you to get an x-value between 0 and 300 (your width) and then add 100 to it (your origin). Same will be required for y-value, get a random value between 0 and 200 (height) and add 50 (origin) to it.

Comment: This is a perfect answer to your question.  I don't know what else you need.